# grails create js file and refer it from gsp

Tags: javascript, grails

i did a simple js within web-app/js/time.js which is

/**
 * Created by User on 28-01-2015.
 */

```
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
```

and in my gsp i did this to refer this js function

```
<div id="loginHeader">
        <g:javascript src="time.js" id="demo" />
    </div>
```

but it is not showing on my gsp page, however if i put this script in the gsp page it works fine like

```
<div id="loginHeader">
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
        function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
        }
        var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
        </script>
    </div>
```

i just want put this script into js file and call it from gsp page, so anyone can help me find out whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I find out the answer see following codes 
the js.file

```
 function myTimer() {
        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
 }
 var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
```

the gsp

```
<div id="loginHeader">
    <g:javascript src="time.js" />
    <p id="demo1"></p>
</div>
```